# on mouse move fill container with color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

Say i have a div 100px width by 40px height and the background of orange. I would like to run my mouse through the div from left to right and as the mouse moves it should fill the div with the color green. Once the mouse gets past the end of the div the color should stay green. if the mouse cursor comes out of the div before passing the end the color should animate/fill back up to orange. Also the mouse should have to start from the begining ( 0px ) of the div for the mousemove effect to start otherwise it should do nothing.

I have spent a few days on this and its driving me crazy.

heres a fiddle of what I have so far

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/7my7etzm/

Comment: Where's your code? We won't write it for you, but we'll help you with what you've come up with for the past "few days"

Comment: So, you want the green to track with the mouse? Or you want it to be a fluid, triggered animation?

Comment: wow give me a chance before down voting its been 1 minute, I will post it now.

Comment: green to track with the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $orangeBox = $(".orangeBox"),
      $greenBox = $(".greenBox"),
      $goalPosts = $(".goalPosts"),
      winning = function() {
        $orangeBox.unbind('mousemove').unbind('mouseleave');
        $goalPosts.remove();
      };
  
  $orangeBox.bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    var xPosition = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    $goalPosts.show();
    $greenBox.css('width', xPosition);
    if (xPosition > $orangeBox.outerWidth()) {
      winning();
    }
  })
  .bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if($greenBox.outerWidth() < ($orangeBox.outerWidth() - 1)) {
      $greenBox.animate({
        width: "0"
      }, 500);
      $goalPosts.hide();
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
.orangeBox{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
  background:orange;
}
.greenBox {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:green;
}
.goalPosts {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="orangeBox">
  <div class="greenBox"></div>
  <div class="goalPosts"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is really good but I wanted it so you have to come in from the left, in this example you can start in the middle or the end.

Comment: I just added the code to always detect the escape on the right. If you want to ensure they come in from the left, you could apply the same type of logic for the in as well. Make sense? Or do you want me to mock that up as well?

Comment: I also made it so once it is successful the effects are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very quick and basic solution, i hope it helps a bit

[`solution` on js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdq5z7ej/1/)

ps: the framerate should be tweaked because it fails when fast moving the mouse

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8w1qxze/) is your simplest working demo. i am sure you can improve this.

```
solution https://jsfiddle.net/h8w1qxze/
```